# Maximum call stack size exceeded when using the new typescript enabled version of reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-orm

I use the new typescript supported version of reactjs

along with the redux-orm and when u try to insert a value into the store i get this issue of "Maximum call stack size exceeded" the same works with the old template

Below is the code with new typescript supported reactjs which throws the error
https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#typescript and the old github version https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter which works.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15eolNjeYroyubgSmbGaaKfjxbe-IZ8KK

I am unable to understand what is different that causes the error with the new version. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have recursion somewhere in your code that is calling itself over and over again nonstop and as the stack rises it exceeded and throws an error

Comment: The same code works for the older version of react typescript template where has the recently added typescript supported throws this error.

Answer (score -1):

Properties can't be defined directly on Model classes.

The root cause lies in the **create-react-app**'s babel preset - transpilation output introduces additional property descriptors in **Model** prototype chain.

These properties interfere with descriptors installed by **redux-orm** during schema registration, resulting in `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

This can be avoided through declaration merging, specifically by providing a class and an interface with matching names. The interface contains `Model` properties, the class is almost 1:1 to JS `Model` definition.

Example:

```js
interface Book {
    id: number
    title: string
}

class Book extends Model<typeof Book> {
    static modelName = 'Book' as const

    static fields = {
        id: attr(),
        title: attr()
    }
}
```

I've created a repo with working example: https://github.com/tomasz-zablocki/redux-orm-ex-types-react-example

Mind you, these are custom types, but it's definitely where I'd like to take the `@types/redux-orm` package to, likely with the 0.14 release of `redux-orm`.

Comment: I was aware of the syntax of using the Model<typeof Question> which in itself implements the properties due to the "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" issue that is raised we wanted a simler working version of the Model. The Old template supports the inline assignments of properties where as the new one throws the "maximum call stack size exceeded" error. Is there a way i can with the new template use the simpler Model syntax with implementing the properties of the interface ?